# Resize torch tensor channels

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a torch tensor with 3 channels, and I want it to be 1 channel (all other dimensions should stay the same).
So if my current dimensions are `torch.Size([6, 3, 512, 512])` I want it to be `torch.Size([6, 1, 512, 512])`

How can I do that?

Comment: How do you want to collapse the 3 channels into 1? Take their average value? Their max? Sum? Delete two of the channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
a = torch.ones(6, 3, 512, 512)
b = a[:, 0:1, :, :]
print(b.size()) # torch.Size([6, 1, 512, 512])
```